# Return JSONObject from servlet throws exception

Tags: java, javascript, json, jquery, servlets

I have a servlet to which I am posting data from ajax(jquery) call.

```
$('form').submit(function() {
var URL = "ProjectHandler"; 
var dataString=$(this).serialize();
$.ajax({
       type: "POST",
       url: URL,
       data: dataString, 
      // dataType: json,
       success: function(data)
       {
           alert(data.error);

       }
     });
    return false; 
});
```

I have commented dataType beacause when I uncomment it, it doesnt make ajax call, rather, the form is submitted with default mode i.e. the servlet is loaded

JAR's I have added to the project 1. json-lib-2.2.2-jdk15.jar 2. apache-commons-lang.jar 3. ezmorph-1.0.jar

first it threw exception filenotfound which was part of apache-commons package so included apache commons, after that I got exception of filenotfound which was part of ezmorph-1.0.jar, so I added that also. Now I am getting

```
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.commons.logging.LogFactory
```

Code in servlet doPost:

```
response.setContentType("application/json");
PrintWriter out = response.getWriter();

JSONObject json  = new JSONObject();
json.put("error", true);
json.put("errorDesc", "wrong title");
out.print(json);
```

I hope I have cleared the scenario, any help would be appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: googling for exception will help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you are missing the commons-logging.jar. Add it to your classpath.

Comment: now this exception java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.commons.collections.map.ListOrderedMap

Comment: wait, now I have added whole apache-commons.jar which has all the commons packges, now I am getting this exception java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.slf4j.LoggerFactory

Comment: dude, every time you get an error like this, just find the jar that contains that class and add it to the classpath

Comment: ohh I am feeling like this gonna be a never ending addition of jar's, because adding one producing some other exception

Comment: see, adding that getting new one java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.slf4j.impl.StaticLoggerBinder

Comment: Usually libraries like slf4j have a general purpose jar that contains all jars and a more specific jars that contain certain functionality, make sure you include the all-in-one jar.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/19712/discussion-between-vikas-devde-and-ftom2)

Answer (score 0):

Can you drop json-lib? If yes do it! Honestly there is no reason to use this library...the fact that it requires you to add tons of dependencies prooves it.

I would suggest you try Genson library http://code.google.com/p/genson/. It has the advantage to be easy to use but powerfull, extensible, all in one and fast.
It would allow you to deserialize/serialize directly to pojos, no need to use all those JsonObject/Arrays... You can also directly use its streaming API if you need something close to manual json in term of performances.